# SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\ProyectoSecretoo\src\producto.php on line 57

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

La función actualizar es la que me da error.

El error me lo da el archivo **`acciones.php`**, ya lo he revisado varias veces si el error era alguna palabra mal escrita, pero creo que no hay ningún error de esos.

```
public function actualizar($_params){
    $sql = "UPDATE `producto` SET `titulo`=:titulo,`descripcion`=:descripcion,`foto`=:foto,`precio`=:precio,`productos_id`=:produtos_id,`fecha`=:fecha WHERE `id`=:id";
    
    $resultado = $this->cn->prepare($sql);
    
    $_array = array(
        ":titulo" => $_params['titulo'],
        ":descripcion" => $_params['descripcion'],
        ":foto" => $_params['foto'],
        ":precio" => $_params['precio'],
        ":productos_id" => $_params['productos_id'],
        ":fecha" => $_params['fecha'],
        ":id" => $_params['id']
    );

    if($resultado->execute($_array)) //línea 57 (línea del error).
        return true;

    return false;
?>
```

Este es el archivo html, intentado buscar algún error aquí encontré algunos, pero ninguno estaba causando el error "*SQLSTATE[HY093]*"

```
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Datos del Producto</legend>
                <form method="POST" action="../acciones.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php print $resultado["id"]; ?>">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Nombre:</label>
                                <input value="<?php print $resultado["titulo"]; ?>" type="text" class="form-control" name="titulo" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Descripción:</label>
                                <textarea class="form-control" name="descripcion" id="" cols="3" required><?php print $resultado['descripcion']; ?></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>opcional:</label>
                                <select class="form-control" name="categoria_id" required>
                                    <option value="">--SELECCIONA--</option>
                                    <option value="1">SABOR</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Foto:</label>
                                <input type="file" class="form-control" name="foto">
                                <input type="hidden" name="foto_temp" value="<?php print $resultado['foto']?>">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Precio:</label>
                                <input value="<?php print $resultado['precio']?>" type="text" class="form-control" name="precio" placeholder="0.00" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div> 

                    <input type="submit"class="btn btn-primary" name="accion" value="ACTUALIZAR">
                    <a href="index.php" class="btn btn-default"> CANCELAR</a>

                </form>

            </fieldset>
        </div>
    </div>
</div> <!-- /container -->
```

Este es el archivo php que me muestra el error que hay en el archivo **`producto.php`**. Este archivo se llama **`acciones.php`**:

```
    if($_POST['accion'] === 'ACTUALIZAR'){

    if(empty($_POST['titulo']))
    exit('Completa el nombre');

if(empty($_POST['descripcion']))
    exit('Completa la descripción');

if(empty($_POST['categoria_id']))
    exit('Selecciona producto');

if(!is_numeric($_POST['categoria_id']))
    exit('Selecciona una producto válido');

    $_params = array(
        'titulo'=>$_POST['titulo'],
        'descripcion'=>$_POST['descripcion'],
        'precio'=>$_POST['precio'],
        'productos_id'=>$_POST['categoria_id'],
        'fecha'=> date('Y-m-d'),
        'id'=>$_POST['id'],
    );

    if(!empty($_POST['foto_temp']))
        $_params['foto'] = $_POST['foto_temp'];
    
    if(!empty($_FILES['foto']['name']))
        $_params['foto'] = subirFoto();



    $rpt = $producto->actualizar($_params);
    if($rpt)
        header('Location: productos/index.php');
    else
        print 'Error al actualizar';

    }
```

Espero que me puedan ayudar, llevo más de una hora buscando el error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando tengas este tipo de errores **revisa minuciosamente cómo estás escribiendo los parámetros**. En ese sentido, escribir tu consulta identada ayudará a hacer una revisión con mayor facilidad.

Si observas bien, tienes un error en este parámeto: **`:produtos_id`**, ahí falta una `c`.

Voy a escribir la consulta identada, verás que es más simple de comparar con con el array:

```
public function actualizar($_params){
    $sql = "UPDATE `producto` SET 
               `titulo`=:titulo,  
               `descripcion`=:descripcion, 
               `foto`=:foto, 
               `precio`=:precio, 
               `productos_id`=:productos_id, 
               `fecha`=:fecha 
             WHERE 
               `id`=:id";
    
    $resultado = $this->cn->prepare($sql);
    
    $_array = array(
        ":titulo" => $_params['titulo'],
        ":descripcion" => $_params['descripcion'],
        ":foto" => $_params['foto'],
        ":precio" => $_params['precio'],
        ":productos_id" => $_params['productos_id'],
        ":fecha" => $_params['fecha'],
        ":id" => $_params['id']
    );

// ... resto del código
```

### Recomendaciones

En tu código hay mejoras que deberías emprender, por ejemplo, no tienen sentidos los dos `return` seguidos. El `return false` debería estar en un `else`.

Por otra parte, deberías controlar que aquellos datos del `$_POST` que tuvieren restricción `NOT NULL` en la definición de la tabla no estén vacíos o sean nulos.

Comment: Gracias, no me había fijado en esa c que faltaba, ya tenía horas trabajando, creo que por eso no lo vi.

Comment: Y gracias por la recomendación.